# mono develop Combobox Entry - Autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, combobox, monodevelop

I am trying to make a window form in Mono develop.
in the form, I need a Combobox Entry with Autocomplete/AutoSuggest feature.

Could any one guide me how to do it?

Comment: Did this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check this feature out on an Entry field called EntryCompletion:

```
Entry entry = new Entry ();
entry.Completion = new EntryCompletion ();
```

There is an an [example here](https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/blob/master/sample/GtkDemo/DemoEntryCompletion.cs) of doing an search auto complete.

Edit:

Here is the [Documentation for the feature with the same example](http://api.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aGtk.EntryCompletion)